# Adding powershell and other packets to winre.wim doesnt work (0x800f081e)

Tags: windows, powershell, mount, dism, wim

as the question tells im trying to add powershell as a feature to a pxe bootable winRE.wim. I get the errorcode 0x800f081e and it says the packet is not valid for this image. For a better look, you can also see it in this image:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CjsE.png)

I know its german but it says something like "package is not suitable for that image" implying the versions differ from another. Im using a 1803 version and the packet should be the same. I tried installing other packets which could be necessary prior to installing powershell, but they also do not work.

The errorcode is 0x800f081e and it say the windows

Comment: PLEASE, don't post images of code/errors/data. why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: sorry you are right, this was kinda stupid. I edited the post giving a brief explanation of the errorcode but leaving the image for an additional visual value

Comment: did you google the errorcode and try what the results suggest? When I google it I see that this errorcode quite often happens with version 1803

Comment: @J.Doe - please post the full text of the error so that folks can easily copy that to a search box, or otherwise use the text AS TEXT.